# una alerta de sweetalert2 no funciona

Tags: sweetalert

Lo siguiente es mi código para intentar eliminar un registro de una base de datos y que una vez eliminado me muestre la alerta de que ha sido eliminado. Sucede que me muestra la alerta diciéndome que un registro eliminado no se puede recuperar, si le doy en cancelar me enseña la alerta de que mi registro está seguro; pero sí le digo eliminar no me muestra ninguna alerta, sin embargo sí que elimina el registro de la base de datos. Se comporta como si ni llegara al `if`, es decir, ni entra al `if` ni hace la alerta del `else` de ese `if`, o sea, no llega al `if`. Me pueden ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

```
//***Eliminar un registro existente***

    $('.borrar_registro').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var tipo = $(this).attr('data-tipo');
    var agentecom = $(this).attr("data-agente") ;
    agente = agentecom.replace(/["']/g, "");

    const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
    buttonsStyling: false,
    });

    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
    title: '¿Estás segur@ ?',
    text: "Un registro eliminado no se puede recuperar!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Sí, Eliminar',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
    reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    data: {
    'id': id,
    'registro': 'eliminar',
    'agente': agente
    },
    url: 'modelo-'+tipo+'.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    var resultado = data;//JSON.parse(data);
    //console.log(resultado);
    if(resultado.booleano === true){
    //$("[data-id='"+resultado.id_eliminado+"']").parent('tr').remove();
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
    'Eliminado!',
    'Su registro ha sido eliminado.',
    'success'
    );
    }else{
    Swal.fire(
    "Error!",
    "No se pudo eliminar, intente de nuevo.",
    "error"
    );//Aquí añadí un punto y coma por sugerencia del hosting
    }
    }
    });
    } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
    'Cancelado',
    'Su registro está seguro :)',
    'error'
    );
    }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Sucede que el ajax manda a llamar a un archivo php que ejecuta la comunicación con la base de datos y la sentencia eliminar un registro; y dependiendo de lo ejecutado genera un array u otro array que finalmente devuelve como JSON:encode. Es precisamente en ese if donde comparo el valor de una clave que viene en el json, si su valor es exito dispara la alerta de 'success' y si el valor es error dispara la otra alerta en este caso de 'error'.

Comment: Pero gracias rances5171 por tu ayuda, tendré en cuenta la forma que me propones y veré si satisface lo que me propongo.

Comment: Rances5171, nuevamente gracias por responderme, pero no me funciona, es decir, borra el registro (eso siempre lo ha hecho) pero no se ejecuta la alerta de success sino la de error; en otras palabras, dentro del ajax no entra a la function success sino a la function error (dentro de cada función puse solamente la alerta correspondiente)

Answer (score 0):

¿Para que quieres hacer un IF ?  las funcione Ajax cuentan con dos opciones

```
    success: function(){
            //ALerta exito
    },
    error: function(){
            //alerta Error
    }
```